# API Facebook - Pegar foto(com tamanho definido) com outras informações(nome, email, id)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, facebook

Preciso pegar os id,nome,email e foto da pessoa ao clicar em entrar.

Estou fazendo assim até o momento porém está com problemas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      testAPI();
    }else if(response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }else{
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  function checkLoginState() {

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }



  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxx',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.6' // use version 2.2
    });


  };


  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
      data_facebook = {id_facebook:response.id, name:response.name, email:response.email};
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';

       FB.api('/me/picture?width=400&height=400', function(response) {
         data_facebook.picture = response.data.url;
          $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/teste/facebook',
            data: {id_facebook: data_facebook.id_facebook, name: data_facebook.name, email: data_facebook.email, picture: data_facebook.picture}
          })
          .success(function(data){
            //window.location.href = '/teste/facebook';
          });
        console.log(data_facebook);
       });
    });

  }
</script>
```

As vezes o ajax pega os valores do data_facebook e as vezes não. Parece que está rodando cedo demais, sei la.

Coloquei FB.api dentro de FB.api e acredito que está errado tbm.

Answer (score 1):

Tira e testa novamente pois o meu funcionou

```
 function checkLoginState() {

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
```